# How to get the names of files in a folder on your server, and put them into an html list

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html, jsoup

I have tried looking a few times on Google and didn't really find any answer, so I'm hoping I can get some help here.

I am trying to get the contents of a user's folder and display it within an html list.

So for example if I have some folder on my server named "Names" and within this folder were 5 different names.  I want to take those names, and display them in a list.

I originally was accomplishing this task by using http://jsoup.org/

I would go to the folder based on the username they logged in with, grab the data, and display it in a list using JSTL.

```
   <c:forEach items="${url.PNV}" var="l" varStatus="stat4">
        <li>
           <a href="#">${l}</a>
       </li>
  </c:forEach>





UrlReader.java



   public class URLReader implements Serializable 
 {
    private List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    private String url = "";

     public URLReader() throws IOException
     {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
        Elements links = doc.select("a[href]");

        for (Element link : links)
        {
            if (link.text().contains(".txt")) 
            {
                list.add(link.text());
            }
        }
     }
 }
```

However I have changed my approach and am not using java on my server currently, so I wanted to know if there was another way to do this using JS, Jquery or w/e.  If there isn't an easier way, or no other known way, then I will just do with what I have.

Thank you all!

Comment: Unless your server is runing `node.js`, you can not directly get the information from your server using *javascript* (and *jQuery* because it is javascript.), because it is running in the client. (*browser*) all it can do is to request the server for the information. You should have a server side script, java,php,c# or whatever to get that information and sent it back to client so that it can display the data...

Comment: Thanks... Is there a better way to do this with Java than to use JSoup?

From what I see now Jsoup is usually based on a full URL.

I have not tried using a relative URL from my application, but I hope that works.  i.e., my application will be in some folder on my server and ../users/username/data is where the data is.